# URL redirect in IIS

Tags: redirect, iis

I'm redirecting all files in a specific directory to a new directory. When I set this up in IIS it redirects but it loses the file name. What do I need to specify that the file name should be passed to the redirect? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added .* after the slash like this: ^aboutus/.* and that solved the issue of file names not being passed in the redirect.